# Failed to install extundelete-0.2.0 on CentOS 5.6, "error: can't find ext2fs library"

Tags: linux, centos

```
 ./configure
Configuring extundelete 0.2.0
configure: error: Can't find ext2fs library
```

It looks to me it's something related to e2fsprogs, however my OS has below software installed,

```
yum list |grep e2fs
e2fsprogs.i386                           1.39-33.el5                   installed
e2fsprogs-libs.i386                      1.39-33.el5                   installed
e2fsprogs-devel.i386                     1.39-33.el5                   base
```

Comment: I'm more interested in what you're undeleting :)

Comment: some log files are rolled over-_-

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The package you need is not actually installed. Please run `yum install e2fsprogs-devel.i386` and try again.

Note that the last column in your yum listing shows "installed" for the first two packages, but shows "base" for the last. That indicates that the package is part of the base group but is not installed.

You *may* also need to remove the `config.cache` file in your extundelete source directory before running `./configure` again.

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu I had to install the `e2fslibs-dev` package

Answer (score 2):

for someone looking for the same lib in the MacOSX:
ext2fs_open is inside e2fsprogs package which is available to install from homebrew with the following command:

```
brew install e2fsprogs
```

but the configure will fail to find the `libext2fs.a` in the default path, so use following escape command to be able to extract correct path:

```
LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix e2fsprogs)/lib"
```